# Node.js http server, function can't access response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have the following http server code

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, response) {
    body = "";
    req.on("data", function (data) {
    body += data;
  });
  req.on("end", function (){
    parseRequest(body);
  });
}).listen(8080);

var parseRequest = function (data) {
  try {
    jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    handleRequest(jsonData);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log("Json Parse Failed")
    console.log(e);
    response.writeHead(500);
    response.end("Json Parse Failed");
  }
}
```

I thought that the parseRequest function should be able to access it's variables in in its parent function's scope. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

The error I get is,

```
response.writeHead(500);
^
ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

Comment: Variable declared inside the scope of a function are limited to that scope unless declare globally. so you need `parseRequest` inside the same scope as response if you want it to use response.

Comment: "*access it's variables in in its parent function's scope*" - yes, it does. Only the scope of the `createServer` callback **is not** the parent scope of `parseRequest`. Move it inside there and it would work.

Comment: Btw, you are missing [`var`iable declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for `body` and `jsonData`. Please use strict mode to avoid such accidental globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
req.on("end", function (){
    parseRequest(response, body);
});
```

And then:

```
var parseRequest = function (response, data) { ...
```

And now you can access response. ;)

Comment: I know I could do this, but it seems inefficient.

Comment: What is inefficient about this?

Comment: Inefficient? If you don't propagate the variables you need to your method scope, you have no chance to access them.

Comment: I checked, this worked in the chrome js console,`a = function(b){x=b;d()};d = function(){console.log(x)};a("hi");` prints hi.

Comment: Because in this example, it's declared in the scope enclosing your function

Comment: Would this scope be window?

Comment: And is there a way to do this without recreating the function on every request?

Comment: Yes, because variables that are not declared by "var" are added to the global scope. So x refers to window.x

Comment: You could attach the body and the response to the req and then refer to this inside the req callbacks but that might be a little over the top and not really worth it for such small functions. But it's always good to learn early that reusing is usually the better option than recreating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, response) {
  var body = "";
  req.on("data", function (data) {
    body += data;
  });
  var parseRequest = function (data) {
    try {
       var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
       handleRequest(jsonData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Json Parse Failed")
      console.log(e);
      response.writeHead(500);
      response.end("Json Parse Failed");
    }
  };
  req.on("end", function (){
    parseRequest(body);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Why would you create a new function per request if there is no need for it?

Comment: @SebastianNette: Now he's creating 3 instead of 2 functions per request. Doesn't seem to be a large difference.